# Can't access Root File Folder

Tags: root

I just installed Ubuntu 11.0 and when I try to go into Root folder to add new wirless drivers it says I don't have permissions to access the root folder even though I am the only user on the computer and I am an administrator.  How do I fix this?

Comment: you need to use `sudo` ---> but can you explain exactly what you are trying to do - which windows, messages etc What driver are you installing, from where, using what instructions?

Answer (score 4):

If you are a fan of GUIs, press Alt-F2 and type:

gksu nautilus

You will have complete control over everything; you can delete, add, copy, paste, etc. with complete control and complete permission.